# Google Compute Engine Ubuntu 17.04 zesty does no longer have a Release file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, apt, ubuntu-17.04

I have just created a new Google Cloud Compute Engine server using Ubuntu 17.04 as the boot disk:

```
Ubuntu 17.04
amd64 zesty image built on 2017-12-08
```

Before doing anything else, if I try to run `sudo apt-get update` I receive the following errors:

```
Ign:1 http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Ign:2 http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates 

InRelease
Ign:3 http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease             
Err:5 http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release        
  404  Not Found [IP: 35.195.241.40 80]
Err:6 http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 35.195.241.40 80]
Err:7 http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 35.195.241.40 80]
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Hit:9 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                    
Reading package lists... Done                          
E: The repository 'http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security Release' does no longer have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Looking at http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ I can see updates from today less than an hour ago.

Is this an error on Google's side or have I done something wrong?

Comment: Zesty is no longer supported, so you have to upgrade it, as Denis suggested

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I confirm that "E: The repository 'http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does no longer have a Release file."

Solved as proposed before by [heroin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2982798/heroin) in the recipe https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/ .

> Run this command below on your server and it will replace all of the  archive.ubuntu.com  and  security.ubuntu.com package repository URLs with  old-releases.ubuntu.com
>
> sudo sed -i -e 's/archive.ubuntu.com\|security.ubuntu.com/old-releases.ubuntu.com/g' /etc/apt/sources.list

Unfortunately this sed command will not work for you if you have selected a national mirror (like `us.archive.ubuntu.com` for updates. Then one can update strings in the file /etc/apt/sources.list changing all entries like `http://*.archive.ubuntu.com` and `http://*.security.ubuntu.com` to the `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com` manually in a text editor,

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

or

```
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

For example, your `http://europe-west1.gce.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease` become `http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease` and so on.

Here is my updated file /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412)]/ zesty main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ zesty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty partner

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security multiverse
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  My main issue with switching to 17.10 is GitLab runners aren't (yet) supported.  I have been able to work a temporary fix to this, as everything else is fine with 17.10. This is a great alternative for the existing servers thank you.

Answer (score 8):

17.04 is now end of life as of January 13, 2018. You will need to move to a newer version or use a long term stable version:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Comment: But the question is specific to Google Cloud Compute Engine and the `/etc/apt/source.list` definition.  It makes no sense for GCE to offer Ubuntu 17.04 and then not support **their own** definition in the above file.  They also offer Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04, both of which I can spin up and run 'sudo apt-get update` without any errors (although I appreciate these are long-term stable versions). This feels like an error on their part, but your link suggests they should no longer offer 17.04...

Comment: I can confirm that the issue is due to the same reason as mentioned by @Jeremy. I have reached out to the backend team to update GCE Ubuntu 17.04 image.

Comment: @Faizan I can confirm the Ubuntu 17.04 image has been removed from the list of boot disks on GCE.  Unfortunately, that doesn't help me!

Comment: Follow Denis answer, and you have the solution, chapmanio. It shouldn't be a problem with Google Cloud Computer Engine, you should be able to edit the /etc/apt/sources.list file, and then do a `sudo do-release-upgrade` as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Zesty does no longer have a release file, indeed "END OF LIFE CYCLE "

I had the same problem, the solution is in this link, it works for me...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Hope my answer would help.

Comment: Please read: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: That is the right answer, but Denis put the sources together to an answer that isn't dependent on links that can break.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be not with a Google's side, but with the fact that you are trying to get updates from HTTP and not HTTPS.

Try to use this option of apt-get:

```
--allow-unauthenticated
       Ignore if packages can't be authenticated and don't prompt about it. This can be useful while working with local repositories, but is a huge security risk if data authenticity isn't ensured in another way by the
       user itself. The usage of the Trusted option for sources.list(5) entries should usually be preferred over this global override. Configuration Item: APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated.
```

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get update --allow-unauthenticated` returns exactly the same error message I'm afraid!    
I haven't changed any configuration, etc. from the default server set up from GCE, so I haven't told apt to get updates over http, this is the default behaviour.

Comment: Can you try ``sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated update`` ?

Comment: Same error message again.  This is surely an issue at Google's side?  I've just created a server, SSH'd in and run that command without doing anything else...

Comment: Probably, the issue is that your version of Ubuntu is not supported anymore (as 17.04 is not an LTS and 9 months of support should have already passed today). Why not just to try a fresher version?

Comment: Although, you may try solution proposed here: https://smyl.es/how-to-fix-ubuntudebian-apt-get-404-not-found-package-repository-errors-saucy-raring-quantal-oneiric-natty/ (I didn't tried it).

Comment: I tried that just now. It did not help with the Zesty release problem

Comment: zesty isn't supported anymore, as heroin suggested.  Follow +Denis Trofinov answer and you will find the solution.  I hade the same problem, and that is the solution.  Changing repositories to old-release.ubuntu.com as his sed-script will do.